# Electron not working on Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, electron

At the moment, I am developing a "kiosk" application for my Raspberry Pi. I decided to use [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) as it offers the key feature I need: Combining a web based UI with direct system an I/O access via node.js.

However, Electron refuses to run on my Raspberry Pi whereas it works just fine on the computer I am using for development. Nothing happens after issuing `electron .` in the terminal, the program just exits without showing a window or any errors in the command line. Any clues? I couldn't find any on the web so far. I installed Electron via `npm install electron-prebuilt -g`, which downloaded and installed the latest ARM-version.

If this is an unresolvable compatibility problem: Are there any good alternatives for Electron?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you manage to find a solution for this by now?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solutution yet - I'm still working on it

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on your setup? Which distribution to you use? How did you install nodejs? Which version of nodejs have you installed?

Comment: I use the Raspbian distribution as it was installed already for previous projects. Then I installed electron via the node package manager which I did successfully on my working machine as well. Nevertheless, (for private reasons) I won't be able to investigate this issue any further during the next two or three weeks. A recent suspicions is that there is just not enough RAM in order to execute Electron.

Comment: I tried it at home today with a newer raspbian version and a 16GB SD Card. The examples taken from https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps now work for me.
So it's either free space or the newer raspbian version.

Comment: Thanks for for this update - I'll try as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the reason for that error is that Electron currently does not support ARM devices. We will have to wait until it is implemented

See this issue https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/1702

## -- Update

As noted by @skeggse, Electron now does support ARM.

- 1 Get the dependecies going `apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 libnotify4 libgconf2-4 libnss3 node npm`
- 2 Download the latest **arm** release called **electron-...-linux-arm.zip** from [here](https://github.com/atom/electron/releases)
- 3 `unzip electron-...-linux-arm.zip`
- 4 go inside the folder and double click the file named **electron**
- 5 Have fun!

Comment: I don't think that's right - that issue is closed, and if you follow the issue chain you find [#2094](https://github.com/atom/electron/pull/2094) which indicates that they cross-compile for ARM. It's entirely possible that their ARM cross-compile is incompatible with RPi, in which case (as @user650881 noted), you should compile from source.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which Raspberry Pi you have it may be an incompatible binary.  The electron prebuilt binaries, I believe, target armv7-hf.  Try building electron from source.  The instructions can be found here https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/development/build-instructions-linux.md

Note that if you are interested in using hardware float support (at least prior to RPiB+) you might want to run Raspbian or another port with hard-float support. ([ref](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianFAQ#What_is_Raspbian.3F))

Comment: Build Electron, directly on an rPi? `Prerequisites: At least 25GB disk space and 8GB RAM.`

Answer (score 1):

Connect to Raspberry SSH as user ***pi***, and execute this:

```
# Clone this repository
git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
# Go into the repository
cd electron-quick-start
# Install dependencies
npm install
# Set display
export DISPLAY=:0
# Run the app
npm start
```

Comment: the problem is this part: export DISPLAY=:0
thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question. You could try stopping on the first line of your application with:

```
electron --debug-brk=5858 .
```

This would help you determine whether it's an electron issue or an issue with your app.

http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.30.0/tutorial/debugging-main-process/

Comment: `electron --debug-brk=5858 .` produces no output as well. But I don't think it has to du with my app due to its simplicity (Just opens a window with a basic angular js app at the moment). Thanks for your help!